# Ambiguity in accessing the Datatable cells value

Tags: c#, datatable

I have been trying to accessing the DataTable First column first cell value by using the code below. But it returns me NULL or BLANK value.

```
label13.Content = newDt.Rows[0][0].ToString();  //1st CODE
```

Then i tried the following code, it solved my problem. Don't know what was error in my first code.

```
label13.Content = newDt.Rows[0]["BATCH NUM"].ToString();  //2nd COde which solved Problem
```

Any idea what was wrong in first code statement.

Below is a datasource for newDt

```
var newDt = dt.AsEnumerable()
              .GroupBy(r => r.Field<string>("BATCH NUM"))
              .Select(g =>
              {
                   var row = dt.NewRow();
                   row["BATCH NUM"] = g.Key;
          row["QTY"] = g.Sum(r => Convert.ToInt32(r.Field<string>("QTY"))); 

                   return row;
                 }).CopyToDataTable();
```

Comment: Can you add data source as well for this data table

Comment: i have updated my question. And added source of newDT

Comment: Can you conform one thing, Is "BATCH NUM" is first column in your dt? I guess it's not. That's y you are getting null/blank. Actually you are creating new row from existing datatable. So the order of columns will be same as dt. So please check that once.

Comment: Yes BATCH NUM is first column of my Datatable

Comment: Strange thing is that when i do newDt.Row[0][1] then it displays value of QTY column.

Comment: From the issue you are getting it seems like its not. can you share how you are creating dt. I guess there you are not BATCH NUM adding as first column. That is because may be in your dt as well the second column is QTY.

Comment: What you can do to verify quickly, look for dt.Columns then you will have better idea of how columns are present in which order. Then may be you can change the way of creation of your dt if you really needed to put BATCH NUM as first column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because `BATCH NUM` is not at the index 0. Look at the sample below. If you really need to use index to select column then you have to get it as sample code below.

I believe the index is not `0`

```
    var index = dt.Columns["BATCH NUM"].Ordinal;
    var batchNum = dt.Rows[0][index]?.ToString();
```

Below code is to simulate the problem

```
    var dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("BATCH NUM", typeof(string));
    dt.Columns.Add("QTY", typeof(int));

    var row = dt.NewRow();
    row["BATCH NUM"] = 1;
    row["QTY"] = 10;

    dt.Rows.Add(row);

    var val1 = dt.Rows[0][0]?.ToString();              //EMPTY
    var val2 = dt.Rows[0][1]?.ToString();              //1
    var val3 = dt.Rows[0][2]?.ToString();              //10

    var val4 = dt.Rows[0]["ID"]?.ToString();           //EMPTY
    var val5 = dt.Rows[0]["BATCH NUM"]?.ToString();    //1
    var val6 = dt.Rows[0]["QTY"]?.ToString();          //10
```